# Core Data managed object context design recommendation

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

We are working on an Enterprise-level application, which will store tens of thousands of objects with Core Data, and we are having issues on several fronts.

---

Our application has several independent systems which operate on the data when needed. These systems include discovery of items, loading of items, synchronization and UI display. If we design our software correctly, there should be little to none merge conflicts due to the different systems modifying same objects. Each system has its own operation queues, all performing in the background. We wish to keep all object creation and modification in the background to minimize UI performance issues, especially during initial ramp up, where thousands of objects might be created from data on the server. Here we have hit several problems with our various design attempts. Huge memory consumption during these ramp ups, and incorrect orchestration of all the contexts and child contexts, causing deadlocks and crashes.
We have attempted the following designs:

- One root `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` managed object context which has one child `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` context. The UI fetched results controllers use this child context to fetch results from. From the `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` child context, we created one `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` child context, which we called "savingContext" and each background operation created a child context of that "savingContext", did its changes, and finally did what we called a "deep save", recursively saving to the top. We initially chose this design to not have to deal with `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notifications from many different child contexts. We wrapped every call to the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` contexts and access to objects with `performBlockAndWait:`. Functionally, this design performed. All changes and inserts were saved to the persistent store, and UI was updated with the changes. This, introduced two issues. One was laggy UI during ramp up because of merged changes going through the `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` child context, and more importantly, very high memory usage during ramp up. We would hit prohibitive RAM usages due to inability to call `reset` recursively on contexts (as the main UI child context is there too) and/or lack of knowledge when to call `refreshObject:mergeChanges:`. So we went a different road.
- Have two top-level contexts linked with the persistent store coordinator, one `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` for save child contexts, and a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` for UI display. The `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` listens to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notifications from the main `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context and merges them in the main thread. Each background operation creates a child context of the main `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context, also with private queue concurrency type, does what it does, performs a "deep save" recursively, which performs a save on the current context, a recursive call of deep save to its parent, calls reset on the current context and saves again. This way we avoid the memory issues, as created objects are released quickly after save. However, with this design, we have hit a plethora of issues such as dead locks, `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exceptions and fetched results controllers not updating the UI despite there being save notifications for the `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` context. This also cause initial load times in the UI to slow a lot. In the previous design, the fetched results controller returned results very fast, while this has the UI blocked for several seconds until the view loads (we initialize the fetched results controller in `viewDidLoad`).

We have tried many intermediate designs, but they all revolve around the same issues, either very high memory usage, fetched results controller not updating the UI or deadlocks and `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exceptions.

---

I am really getting frustrated. I can't but feel as if our designs are overtly complicated for something that should be rather simple, and it is just our lack of understanding some fundamental that is killing us.

---

So what would you guys suggest? What arrangement would you recommend for our contexts? How should we manage different contexts in different threads? Best practices for freeing up inserted objects and resetting contexts? Avoiding dead locks? All help would be appreciated at this point.

---

I have also seen recommendations for the MagicalRecords category. Is it recommended? We have are already invested in using Core Data types, how difficult would it be to migrate using MR?

Comment: I'm having similar problems (architecture one): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999932/core-data-break-retain-cycle-of-the-parent-context/16008470 - What kind of architecture did you go for in the end? Any tips?

Comment: We have a main context and a parent root context. But the root context is only used for saving, so we reset it on every save. We have a myriad of issues. It seems these new features of child and parent contexts are not well thought out and there are many many bugs still unattended by Apple.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the architecture with a root MOC (PrivateQueue) with a child MOC (MainQueue) and reduce memory by adding the ```[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:NO];``` call in ```-didSave``` in some of my ManagedObjects. This breaks apart the retain cycle between the relationships and allows all MOCs to deallocate the objects. Only MOCs with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType seem to have a weird issue that they won't deallocate the objects immediately but on the next save/rollback.

Comment: Wouldn't this only release objects that were saved (which had `hasChanges` to `YES`)? (I am not 100% when `didSave` gets called.)

Comment: The NSManagedObjectContext only retains NSManagedObjects that have changes (think of it as a dynamic strong/weak). As soon as you save, there are no longer changes and all objects are deallocated unless you have retained them yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, to manage your memory, your second architecture gives you much more flexibility.

Second, there are two kinds of memory to manage: malloc-ed memory and resident VM memory. You can have a low malloc-ed memory footprint and still have a large VM resident region. This is due, in my experience, to Core Data aggressively holding on to newly inserted items. I solve this problem with a post-save trimming notification.

Third, MOCs are cheap. Use'em and throw'em away. In other words, release memory early and often.

Fourth, try to do almost nothing data base wise on the main MOC. Yes, this sounds counter-productive. What I mean is that all of your complex queries really should be done on background threads and then have the results passed to the main thread or have the queries redone from the main thread while exploiting the now populated row-cache. By doing this, you keep the UI live.

Fifth, in my heavily multi-queued app, I try to have all of my saves really occur in the background. This keeps my main MOC fast and consistent with data coming in from the net.

Sixth, the NSFetchedResultsController is a quite useful but specialized controller. If your application pushes it outside of its area of competence, it starts locking up your interface. When that happens, I roll my own controller by listening for the -didSave notifications myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What about lock ups? Currently, our app locks up from time to time, for reasons that are unclear to us. It usually locks up when calling `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` after a notification. Can several threads save at the same time? Should contexts be locked?

Comment: Leo, I minimize the time my UI spends locked up in the main MOC by trying to never save any changes from it. I.e. new data merges into it from the background. That keeps the main MOC free. Also, test to see whether the lock up is because you are updating your fetched results controller or just merging the MOCs. (I'm betting the former. You can test by not setting the FRC delegate.) Yes, several threads can save at the same time. As SQLite is a single threaded store, everything is serialized through the PSC -- reads too. As a result, I serialize my writes/saves through my background MOC. Andrew